# Respecting MIT license in JavaScript files

Tags: copyright, licensing

In my website I am using some JavaScript libraries, released under the MIT license.

One of them is:
https://github.com/olado/doT

Now, the MIT license states:

> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

Though, the source code of the minified library only contains:

`/* Laura Doktorova https://github.com/olado/doT */`

So, my question is: since using the library I am, in a way, "distributing" it (the client is getting a copy of it), do I have to replace the comment with the full text of the MIT license? Am I even allowed to do that?

And what about when the comment is something like:

`// doT.js
// 2011-2014, Laura Doktorova, https://github.com/olado/doT
// Licensed under the MIT license.`

(In this case, the comment references the MIT license).

There are many many libraries with comments like this instead of the full MIT license (which is distributed with the library, but in a separate file) including, for instance, jQuery.

Here, I am interested in what I am required to do, not in wht I should do (for a better understanding of the MIT license).

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Hmm... It's okay for the licence to be located in a separate file, and just a small comment in the source code as you have noted. However, I'm somewhat confused. Are you asking whether you need to include the license text in the code you pass to the client?

Comment: Precisely, that's what I'm asking.

Comment: And is the linked JS being copied into the code, or is it being past through a link? I don't know HTML, but something like this: `<script source="JS source.js"></script>`

Comment: It is referenced in the HTML code (something like `<script source="JS source.js"></script>`), but it is not an external reference (it is hosted on my server).